# Изменение состояние компонента runtime

Tags: vue.js, frontend

Есть вот такой компонент

```
            <div
                v-for="(v, i) in block.variants"
                :key="v"
            >
                <radiobutton
                    :checked="()=>checked(i)"
                    v-on:select="select"
                />
            </div>
```

Внутри `checked(i)`прячется это:

```
        checked: function(i) {
            return this.mask[i] === 1;
        },
```

`mask`:

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            mask: null,
        }
    }
```

При вызове `select`, изменяется состояние `mask`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы `checked` у `radiobutton` изменялся runtime, а не только при отрисовке?

Comment: `:checked="checked(i)"` ?

Comment: @MoloF Что не так?

Comment: Приложите минимально воспроизводимый сниппет и конкретно укажите что вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Кажется, ответ где-то тут